# A matching Debug configuration cannot be found in the wxWidgets directory you specified.

Tags: c++, c, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I have tried to setup and create wxWidgets project using wxWindgets installer and code::block-mingw installations.
When I am trying to create a wx-widgets smith project, I have below problem

```
A matching Debug configuration cannot be found in the wxWidgets directory you specified.
This means Debug target of your project will not build
Are you sure you want to continue with these settings ?
```

does anybody have any idea about this and what is the recommended way to setup wxWidgets and code-block in Windows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved by following the exact instruction provided in [Compiling wxWidgets 3.0.0 to develop Code::Blocks (MSW)](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Compiling_wxWidgets_3.0.0_to_develop_Code%3a%3aBlocks_%28MSW%29#Installing_MinGW) section. I couldn't build wxWidgets correctly in windows. After I build wxWidget the same alert message mentioned in the question was popped when creating wxWidgets project using Code::Block but I dismissed and continue to create the project. This time it was worked.

Answer (score 1):

Did you compile your wxWidgets as a debug build? I got the same error, because I only buitl wxWidgets as a release build. However, I didn't intend to use the debug build anyway, because I didn't want to debug it, just use it. So you can continue with your project and then you have to replace the library names with the correct ones. Mostly this means removing the `d` at the end of the library name.

If you want to use a debug build, you have to build wxWidgets as a debug as well.

To fix the library names, you'd have to right-click on your project and go to "Build options... -> Linker settings".

**Update**

To compile it using MingW you have to follow this [guide](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MinGW).

You may also have to adjust the include paths in your build options:

```
D:\src\c\wxWidgets_3.0.0\lib\gcc_lib\msw
D:\src\c\wxWidgets_3.0.0\include
```

And for the linker:

```
D:\src\c\wxWidgets_3.0.0\lib\gcc_lib
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, Actually I used binderies to install wxwidgets on windows and Release build target also gives same like message. Another thing is when creating the project, **code::blocks** IDE expect at least one build target (debug/release).

Comment: I only started using CodeBlocks a few days ago, so I never built a project without that error. Ignoring it and adjusting the libraries worked fine for me though.

Comment: I also continued ignoring this, but then I can't build the project because of errors in platform.h header file, platform.h file has #include "wx/setup.h" and failed to build because of **error: wx/setup.h: No such file or directory**

Comment: Otherwise, If you set-up the things successfully can you share your set of steps with me. I will try to follow your steps. I am using windows 7, code::blocks 13.1 and wxWidgets 3.0.0.

Comment: Maybe you did something wrong, because I use the same configuration and I can work with it. Did you follow the steps of compiling wxwidgets with MingW? Do you have MSYS or Cygwin installed, because that can interfere (it did for me on the first try). Also don't forget to point codeblocks to your wxwidgets directory and setup the include paths.

Comment: I updated my answer to show you the include and library setup. Adjust to your setup.